# Sort date time field based on AM/PM via shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting, time

I am trying to sort these two lines reversely based on date and time, i am using the below command, and it is working fine but not considering AM and PM, so the below two line not sorted correctly as the time of first one is 10 AM while the second one is 2 PM

command:

```
sort -t',' -k2,2 -k7,7r file.csv
```

lines:

before sorting:

```
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,19-NOV-23 10.58.03.000000 AM
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,19-NOV-23 02.48.47.000000 PM
```

lines after sorting (same arrangement)

```
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,19-NOV-23 10.58.03.000000 AM
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,19-NOV-23 02.48.47.000000 PM
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man sort` (GNU sort, that is):

```
-k, --key=KEYDEF
       sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type

KEYDEF  is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position, where
F is a field number and C a character position in the field;  both  are
origin 1, and the stop position defaults to the line's end. - -  
OPTS is one or more single-letter ordering options [bdfgiMhnRrV] - -
```

Field 7 in your data:

```
         1111111111222222222
1234567890123456789012345678
19-NOV-23 10.58.03.000000 AM
19-NOV-23 02.48.47.000000 PM
```

First define reverse (or in the OPTS), field separator and the year (field 7, positions 8 and 9, numeric):

```
sort -r -t, -k7.8,7.9n file
```

Then the month (M ordering option in GNU sort):

```
sort -r -t, -k7.8,7.9n -k7.4,7.6M file
```

Then the day and AM/PM (actually A/P):

```
sort -r -t, -k7.8,7.9n -k7.4,7.6M -k7.1n,7.2n -k7.27 file
```

And then the time part (left for exercise).

With above you get:

```
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,19-NOV-23 02.48.47.000000 PM
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,19-NOV-23 10.58.03.000000 AM
```

Answer (score 2):

The Decorate-Sort-Undecorate idiom applied using any awk, any sort, and any cut:

```
$ awk -F',' -v OFS='\t' '{
    split($NF,t,/[- ]/)
    mthNr = (index("JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC",t[2])+2)/3
    printf "%02d%02d%02d%s%s\t%s\n", t[3], mthNr, t[1], t[5], t[4], $0
}' file.csv | sort -k1,1 | cut -f2-
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,19-NOV-23 10.58.03.000000 AM
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,19-NOV-23 02.48.47.000000 PM
```

```
$ awk -F',' -v OFS='\t' '{
    split($NF,t,/[- ]/)
    mthNr = (index("JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC",t[2])+2)/3
    printf "%02d%02d%02d%s%s\t%s\n", t[3], mthNr, t[1], t[5], t[4], $0
}' file.csv | sort -rk1,1 | cut -f2-
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,19-NOV-23 02.48.47.000000 PM
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,19-NOV-23 10.58.03.000000 AM
```

If you're not sure how that works, look at the output of the `awk` command that adds the key timestamp to (decorates) the input for `sort` to operate on before `cut` (undecorates) removes it again:

```
231119AM10.58.03.000000 field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,19-NOV-23 10.58.03.000000 AM
231119PM02.48.47.000000 field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,19-NOV-23 02.48.47.000000 PM
```

and notice that it will sort alphabetically in the desired order.